# Android Jackson Post

Tags: android, jackson

Uma Dúvida : Estou tentando fazer um post, mas a biblioteca jackson durante o Post não muda o nome do campo durante a serialização, como eu faço isso com Jackson? Minha classe abaixo :

```
@JsonIdentityReference
public class Envio {

    @JsonSerialize
    @JsonProperty("value[teste]")
    Long id;

    @JsonSerialize
    @JsonProperty("label[teste]")
    String name;

    public Envio(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jonathan, seria interessante você postar o código de invocação do serviço rest. E o que ele consome, produz.